# Jenkins Multi Setup Parallel Job

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that requires a specific setup to run it. Since the job gets triggered multiple times often there is queue, so I want to setup jenkins to run the same job in parallel. The question is if I have two setups setupA and setupB and if job1 is being executed sing setupA, how do I configure jenkins job to take setupB for job2? SetupB should only be used if SetupA is being used by another job. Is there a way to configure the jenkins job for this?

Comment: Does setting up as Jenkins slave - say 2 of them where one holds SetupA and other holding SetupB helps? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Comment: @vinWin Thanks. That might help. Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add more slaves to Jenkins Jobs, if jobs are triggered multiple times.

Make sure each and every job point to only agents instead of master. So if multiple jobs are triggered at a time, still Jenkins wont hang.

If Jenkins slave machine have more CPU and RAM, then add more executed to run parallel job on same agent.

- For the master, this is set in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors
- For the slaves (nodes), it is set in Manage Jenkins > Nodes > (each node) > Configure > # of executors

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for how I can have two jobs running parallelly using two different configs (external servers and such). The point being that it is not always necessary to run both of them. The scenario comes up only when one is already busy.